# @ModelAttribute in my REST comes empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, forms, rest

I am trying to pass data through `<select multiple>` from `HTML` to my `RESTful`.
That data is an array of `String`. I don't know why **when it comes to my backend it's empty**.

This is my `REST`:

```
@PutMapping("/events")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<Event> updateEvent(@RequestBody Event event, @ModelAttribute("attendeesToParse") ArrayList<String> attendeesToParse) throws URISyntaxException {
    //Some code
}
```

This is my `HTML`:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Attendees</label>
        <select class="form-control" multiple name="attendeesToParse" ng-model="vm.usernames"
                ng-options="customUser as customUser.username for customUser in vm.customusers">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
</div>
```

I tried to fix this one for days, I googled it so much but I found no solutions. **Please** help me.

I can not change my `HTML` into a `JSP` due to my project's structure and business logic.

Why does it come empty? If I try to show some logs I see an empty array `[]`.

**UPDATE**

My `HTML form call`:

```
<form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate ng-submit="vm.save()">
    <!-- some code -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="vm.clear()">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>&nbsp;<span data-translate="entity.action.cancel">Cancel</span>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="editForm.$invalid || vm.isSaving" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>&nbsp;<span data-translate="entity.action.save">Save</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My `event-dialog-controller.js`: (is the .js controller that works with form)

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('businessRequestApp')
        .controller('EventDialogController', EventDialogController);

    EventDialogController.$inject = ['$timeout', '$scope', '$stateParams', '$uibModalInstance', '$q', 'entity', 'Event', 'Desk', 'CustomUser'];

    function EventDialogController ($timeout, $scope, $stateParams, $uibModalInstance, $q, entity, Event, Desk, CustomUser) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.event = entity;
        vm.clear = clear;
        vm.datePickerOpenStatus = {};
        vm.openCalendar = openCalendar;
        vm.save = save;
        vm.reftables = Desk.query({filter: 'event-is-null'});
        $q.all([vm.event.$promise, vm.reftables.$promise]).then(function() {
            if (!vm.event.refTable || !vm.event.refTable.id) {
                return $q.reject();
            }
            return Desk.get({id : vm.event.refTable.id}).$promise;
        }).then(function(refTable) {
            vm.reftables.push(refTable);
        });
        vm.customusers = CustomUser.query();

        $timeout(function (){
            angular.element('.form-group:eq(1)>input').focus();
        });

        function clear () {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }

        function save () {
            vm.isSaving = true;
            if (vm.event.id !== null) {
                Event.update(vm.event, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
            } else {
                Event.save(vm.event, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
            }
        }

        function onSaveSuccess (result) {
            $scope.$emit('businessRequestApp:eventUpdate', result);
            $uibModalInstance.close(result);
            vm.isSaving = false;
        }

        function onSaveError () {
            vm.isSaving = false;
        }

        vm.datePickerOpenStatus.date = false;

        function openCalendar (date) {
            vm.datePickerOpenStatus[date] = true;
        }
    }
})();
```

My `event-service.js`:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('businessRequestApp')
        .factory('Event', Event);

    Event.$inject = ['$resource', 'DateUtils'];

    function Event ($resource, DateUtils) {
        var resourceUrl =  'api/events/:id';

        return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        data = angular.fromJson(data);
                        data.date = DateUtils.convertLocalDateFromServer(data.date);
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            'update': {
                method: 'PUT',
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    var copy = angular.copy(data);
                    copy.date = DateUtils.convertLocalDateToServer(copy.date);
                    return angular.toJson(copy);
                }
            },
            'save': {
                method: 'POST',
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    var copy = angular.copy(data);
                    copy.date = DateUtils.convertLocalDateToServer(copy.date);
                    return angular.toJson(copy);
                }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

My `event.controller.js`:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
            .module('businessRequestApp')
            .controller('EventController', EventController);

    EventController.$inject = ['Event', 'CustomUser', '$scope'];

    function EventController(Event, CustomUser, $scope) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.events = [];
        vm.customUsers = [];
        vm.usernames = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

        $scope.allCustomUsers = [];

        loadAll();


        function loadAll() {
            Event.query(function (result) {
                vm.events = result;
                vm.searchQuery = null;
            });
            CustomUser.query(function (result) {
                vm.customUsers = result;
                vm.searchQuery = null;
                for (var i = 0; i < vm.customUsers.length; i++) {
                    $scope.allCustomUsers.push(vm.customUsers[i].username);
                }
            });
        }

    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using angularJS, you can't data bind data with @ModelAttribute, because @ModelAttribute exists only with template engines such as JSP, and AngularJS is not a template engine within Spring. Try instead to use @RequestBody on String parameter, and then extract the data using Jackson.

One more issue, How exactly do you pass your values from front to back? I don't see any `$http` angularJS call, and no HTML form with POST method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I got this one: `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.IOException: UT010029: Stream is closed` I tried with `String[]` instead of `ArrayList<String>` but the exception is the same.

Comment: I've read that is possible to have only 1 `@RequestBody` I did a test wrapping all the request content to 1 `String` but my attribute given with `<select>` is still empty. I tested with `@RequestParam` but it says that parameter `attendeesToParse` is empty. How can I fix this?

Comment: I updated all the informations adding all my `.js` files and the code that calls the `HTML` form @MosheArad

Comment: Note that this is a `PUT`, not a `POST` call.

Comment: You can send http body with post and put

Comment: I tried to create a new Java class called `EventDTO` extends `Event` that contains all `Event`'s fields plus `attendeesToParse` but it still doesn't work. I'm finishing ideas...

Comment: `@RequestBody` does not work for `multipart/form-data`, you must use `@ModelAttribute` to upload media. Since `@ModelAttribute` work in `@Create`, there's no reason it does not work on `@Put`